# How do I clear my hotbar in Minecraft Bedrock Edition on PC?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, windows-10

With the console versions of [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) there's a button you can press to clear your hotbar in creative mode (on [xbox-one](/questions/tagged/xbox-one) it's the X button). However, on PC, I'm not seeing any indicator on the screen that it's possible:

[image: Screenshot of open creative inventory on PC.]

I'm aware that I can clear my *inventory* with the `clear` command if I have cheats enabled. However, this clears the *entire* inventory, to include the hotbar. That's not the desired effect, and I'm not seeing anything in the control list in settings that tells me how to do it either.

---

Are there any keystrokes or hotkeys to clear ***just the hotbar***?

Answer (score 2):

How to clear Hotbar on PC Minecraft?
In the survival inventory tab of the creative inventory, ⇧ + Shift + clicking the X clears the whole inventory. In any other tab, ⇧ + Shift + clicking an item puts a stack onto the hotbar. If this doesn't work, I'm sorry, because I only play on bedrock ps4 edition, but I know many Minecraft streamers who use this and it seems to work! Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! Unfortunately, the goal isn't to clear the entire inventory, but thank you for your hotkey contribution! To clarify for future readers, can you update your post to specify that you hold `⇧` + `Shift`? As it stands currently, it doesn't appear to be very clear.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to read the bottom lol. I will do that!

Answer (score 1):

Some of the following may only apply to Minecraft Bedrock for Windows.

**To answer your question specifically**
While in Creative, open your inventory, switch the inventory to Creative using the book icon in the upper right (the same view as your screenshot). Your hotbar will be showing at the bottom but not your stored inventory.
Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on an item in your hotbar and it will be removed from your hotbar, but not dropped into the world.

**Other helpful information**
Pressing 'drop' (<kbd>Q</kbd> by default) while the cursor is hovering over an item in the inventory or a container drops one item.
Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and pressing 'drop' while hovering over a slot in the inventory or container that has one or more items drops the entire stack of items. While venturing without the full inventory open, the same can be applied for the selected item(s) from the hotbar.
Items can also be dropped into the world by clicking outside the inventory window while holding an item with the cursor.